# Type Mismatch in Elm

Tags: elm

I am just starting out learning Elm and I'm having some trouble understanding why I'm getting a type mismatch when passing a custom type into a method that expects... well, what I'm calling a partial type annotation.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
import Debug

type User =
  User { username : String, followers : List User }

type Action = Follow

fromJust : Maybe a -> a
fromJust x = case x of
    Just y -> y
    Nothing -> Debug.crash "error: fromJust Nothing"

update : User 
  -> Action 
  -> { user | followers : List User } 
  -> { user | followers : List User }
update actor action user =
  case action of  
    Follow -> { user | followers = user.followers ++ [actor] }

getUsers : List User
getUsers =
  [
    User { username = "UserA", followers = [] },
    User { username = "UserB", followers = [] }
  ]

main =
  let 
    users = getUsers 
    first = fromJust (List.head users)
    last = fromJust (List.head (List.reverse users))
  in
  show (update first Follow last)
```

And the error output from [elm-lang.org/try](http://elm-lang.org/try):

### Type Mismatch

The 3rd argument to function `update` is causing a mismatch.

43|   show (update first Follow last)
Function `update` is expecting the 3rd argument to be:

```
{ a | followers : List User }
```

But it is:

```
User
```

Hint: I always figure out the type of arguments from left to right. If an
argument is acceptable when I check it, I assume it is "correct" in subsequent
checks. So the problem may actually be in how previous arguments interact with
the 3rd.

---

If I change the type annotation for `update` to expect a `User` instead, I get a different Type Mismatch, saying I should change the types back. :confused:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the recursive type. Elm doesn't seem to have particularly intuitive (to a Haskeller anyway) handling of these, and you have to put some explicit unwraps and wraps in there to make it all work. I assume the compiler guided you to the definition of the `User` type that you have, as it did me when I started playing around with it.

The result of it all is though, values of type `User` in your example aren't records, they're data constructors which take records as a parameter. You have to pattern match against those values in order to get the record out, and remember to include the constructor whenever you return such a value. Fortunately Elm has good pattern matching support or this would be horrific.

So if you change your `update` function to

```
update : User 
  -> Action 
  -> User
  -> User
update actor action (User user) =
  case action of  
    Follow -> User { user | followers = user.followers ++ [actor] }
```

it all works. Note that the parameters are now all `User` types, and the `user` parameter is being deconstructed so we can get at the record inside. Finally, the result is reconstructed with the `User` data constructor.